# Open DBs in parallel using VBA

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have an Access database which is used to calculate performance scores for a large number of people for each day of the week.

Due to the size of the dataset the procedure runs quite slowly. As a potential way to speed this up I am considering a process that would have 5 separate databases that each calculate the scores for one day.

I have written the below VBA code that just opens all of these DBs (Once each DB is open it has it's own autoExec macro that will kick off it's own procedure).

```
Sub DBloop()
 Dim dbArr As Variant
 Dim i As Integer

 dbArr = Array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday")

 For i = 0 To UBound(dbArr)
     openDBs CStr(dbArr(i))
 Next
End Sub

Sub openDBs(dbname As String)
 Dim acc As Access.Application
 Dim DBpath As String
 Dim strDbName As String

 DBpath = "H:\Performance Test\"
 strDbName = DBpath & dbname & ".accdb"

 Set acc = New Access.Application
 acc.Visible = True
 acc.OpenCurrentDatabase strDbName, False
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, what is happening is that as each DB is opened, the initial procedure is waiting for the autoExec macro of that DB to complete before opening the next one. Does anyone know if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: Are you planning to actually split up the data? That will probably cause more trouble than help.

Comment: I was planning too yes. At the moment each person has a separate score for each day. These scores are effectively independent of each other so I did not forsee any issues with splitting it into separate procedures. Is there a potential problem I have overlooked?

Comment: Any sort of query that combines all data would become more difficult. -- It might be worth asking for performance help on your calculation, perhaps it can be sped up greatly.

Comment: Probably the worst db-design ever!?

Comment: What makes you say that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to make sure you don't synchronously open a database.

One of the most simple ones is the following:

```
Application.FollowHyperlink strDbName
```

(no need to create a new Access application object).

Another way is to make the code in your AutoExec macro execute asynchronously. The technique I use for that is the following:

1. Create a hidden form
2. Set it's timer to 1
3. Execute the code, and close the form on the timer

Further ways include things as using `Shell` or the `WScript.Shell` object.

Comment: Thanks Erik, that's great. I think I'll go with the FollowHyperlink one as that seems the most simple :)

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx

> The VBA Shell function can be used to start an external program or perform any operation for which you would normally use the Run item on the Windows start menu.
>   The Shell function starts the command text and then immediately returns control back to the calling VBA code -- it does not wait for the command used in Shell to terminate.

If this is what you want, use `Shell`.

```
' example Access 2010 32bit
Const ACCESS_PATH = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE"""  

Shell ACCESS_PATH & " """ & strDbName & """"
```